# Connecting to MongoDb with SSL from JAVA app

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl

I have a `MongoDb` instance running(single instance) with `SSL` enabled. I am able to connect to it with `RoboMongo` where on `SSL` tab I provide the following :

```
CA File : /path to my certificate/testCA.pem 
PEM certificate/key: /path to my key/testKey.pem
```

Which successfully connects. Now I'm trying to connect to the same mondodb from java app. I imported the testCA.pem into cacerts using the following command:

```
keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file testCA.pem -storepass changeit
```

and I can see a new entry added to the store. Tried to add the other key into it and it says invalid certificate. On the Java app I set system property as following:

```
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_91\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=test.mongo.com:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.io.EOFException}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=test.mongo.com:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.io.EOFException}}]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2075)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1918)
```

What am I missing here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to importing the `CAFile.pem` with the command:

(navigate to your `java_home/jre/lib/security` to run the commands)

`1. keytool -import -trustcacerts -file testCA.pem -keystore cacerts -storepass "changeit"`

I also had to export the `key.pem` into a `pkcs12` format(default password `'changeit'`)

`2. openssl pkcs12 -export -out mongodb.pkcs12 -in testKey.pem`

and in addition to setting system property trustStore/password, keyStore/password should also be set:

```
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",JAVA_HOME + "\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",JAVA_HOME + "\\lib\\security\\mongodb.pkcs12");
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
```

Comment: I have exact same issue, but it is still not working for me, I am running windows so created xyz.pkcs12 from 'testKey.pem' in linux and copied it over to windows and imported the same in keystore, is there any thing else I should do ?

Comment: @Amit can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)

Comment: please let me know if above gives any idea what else can be tried. Thanks

Comment: Only thing is I have self signed certificate created using openssl

Comment: .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).build();
above code allowed me to connect and get passed this issue atleast fr now.

Comment: This answer saved me more n hours of research, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Both the approaches mentioned below usually suggested on forums will *'work'* but are not secure as they disable the host-name verification essentially negating the SSL. Hence they are not recommended especially if your code would be deployed on production:

```
// 1. For any HTTPS connection
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
        new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){
            public boolean verify(String hostname,
                javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                    if(hostname.equals("<hostname>")) {
                        return true; 
                    }
                }
            });

// 2. MongoDB SSL specific 
MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).build();
```

Refer: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation

---

To fix this, you'll need a certificate containing the DNS of the server as a Subject Alternative Name entry, which you can import to your JDK `cacerts`

Alternatively, if you want establish SSL at the application level, I'd recommend creating a `SSLContext` for that particular connection instead of using `System.setProperty()` for setting key-stores/trust-stores. This would help in avoiding conflicts if your application connects to different external services who have different SSL implementations.

---

Specifically for MongoDB, you would just need to append `?ssl=true` at the end of the MongoDBURI after the above mentioned step. If it still doesn't work, I'd recommend updating your JDK version as per https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2184

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the monog db driver to use SSL. You can do this with configuring it manually in a @Configuration class.

```
    public @Bean MongoClient mongo()  {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder options = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true);
        // add more options to the builder with your config
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", options.build());
        return mongoClient;
    }
```

Comment: I enabled SSL  via URI: `test.mongo.com:27017/TestDb?ssl=true`

Comment: afiak Mongo database URI. Cannot be set with host, port and credentials. It uses internal ServerAddress class that accepts only host and port.

Comment: Yes it can be http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/?_ga=1.246548100.1027948420.1459173085'

Comment: ah yes, I was looking at the MongoClient that takes a string. Not the MongoClientURI

Comment: the general format for URI is `mongodb://username:password@mongodb.server.address:portNum/DatabaseName?W=1&ssl=true`. I just need to provide a way to look for the certificates in the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RAD with WAS local servers, you have to add the pem file to the java VM for that server.

So if you have WAS installed to X:\IBM\WASx, X:\IBM\WASx\java_17\jre is the directory that you would navigate and then execute the keytool import there.   Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for **MongoDB Java Driver** 4.x and **MongoDB** 3.x

Where you have to **configure *spring.data.mongodb.xxxx* properties as per your MongoDB**.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

@Configuration
public class MongoClientConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String user;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private char[] password;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private int port;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;
    
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() {
        List<ServerAddress> hosts = Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(host, port));
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, database, password);

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().credential(credential)
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder.hosts(hosts)).build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println("========= MongoClientConfig: " + mongoClient.toString() + "=========");
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        return mongoClient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I download a openssl program from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
   and install it
2. i open a cmd in the foler of my Pem file `certiface.pem`
   and i run a command :

> DIRECTION\OpenSSL\bin\openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.pkcs12
> -in certiface.pem

on password you put what you want example: **blabla**
should create a file name   `keystore.pkcs12`

3. run the command on cmd

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype
> PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

on passwords i put  **blabla**
check that created file `keystore.jks`

4. now my code

   ```
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystore.jks);
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "blabla");
         MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://YOURLINK.mongodb.net/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority");
         database = mongoClient.getDatabase("DatabaseName");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete implementation of how to connect to MongoDB/DocDB over ssl using mongoUri and sslCertificates.
In this implementation, the application itself creates the keystore file and imports the certificate into it. So, there is no need to do any server side changes (in most cases).
https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-boot-aws-documentdb

Answer (score -1):

As Redlab mentioned in the  code, it can be disabled for restricting ssl validation. Specially this case  comes on local setup. No extra effort required to do.

```
public @Bean MongoClient mongo()  {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder options = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(false);
    // add more options to the builder with your config
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", options.build());
    return mongoClient;
}
```

just I modified--
sslEnabled(true) ===> sslEnabled(false).

Comment: I was facing same problem, i resolved it by above way.