# SSL is enabled but the socket is not an instance of javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket java mongodb connection

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, ssl-certificate, jsse

I am trying to connect the MongoDB which is having SSL/TLS enabled along with self signed certificates. I have loaded the self-signed certificate in my local machine cacerts. But getting the exception

```
SSL is enabled but the socket is not an instance of javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
```

References:
[Connecting to MongoDb with SSL from JAVA app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300169/connecting-to-mongodb-with-ssl-from-java-app)

Problem with below code, it accepts all the certificates. I wanted it to be restricted with self-signed certificate that's jvm trust certificates

```java
    public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception {

         String JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_211";
         System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",JAVA_HOME + "\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
         System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","yyyy");
         System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",JAVA_HOME + "\\lib\\security\\mongo.pkcs12");
         System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","xxxx");

         MongoClientURI connectionString;
         String uri = "mongodb://ttt:rrr@1.1.1.1:17017/db?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1";
         MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder;

         optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                 .sslEnabled(true)
                 .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true)
                 .socketFactory(getSSF());

         connectionString = new MongoClientURI(uri, optionsBuilder);
         MongoClient m = new MongoClient(connectionString);
         DB db = m.getDB( "db" );
         DBCollection c = db.getCollection( "mongostudent");

         System.out.println( c.findOne() );
    }

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSSF() throws  NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException{
        SSLContext sslContext;

        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init((KeyManager[])null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

                System.out.println("Certificate:"+x509Certificates[0]);
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

                System.out.println("Certificate:"+x509Certificates[0]);
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }}, new SecureRandom());

        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
}
```

Keytool command used:

1. `keytool -import -trustcacerts -file C:/certificateauth.pem -keystore cacertskeystore.jks -storepass "xxxx"`
2. placed the pkcs file in security folder

I need to configure it in a way so that it accepts only trusted certificate.

Comment: 'The socket is not an instance of `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket`'. Proof? What *is* it an instance of? and what does that have to do with your question? Solution: remove the insecure `TrustManager`. Importing the self-signed certificate into your truststore is sufficient.

Comment: do you mean sslContext.init(null,null,null) ?

Comment: No,. I mean use the default `TrustManager`. I don't see that you even need the explicit `SSLContext`: just use the default one. You haven't answered my question.